# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I am working on a project for finding students grade average for 3 exams.

Everything seems fine with my work but one error I am receiving with the following line:

```
student_avg = ((firstterm) +str (midterm) +str (final)) / 3
```

The program is an instructor's companion app. My professor told me to do 1st term mid term and final for 5 subjects.

After one week of working I still faced some problems on that.
Can anyone review my code and see what my mistake is?

```
def determine_score(grade):
    if 95<= grade <=100:
        return 'A+'
    elif 91<= grade <=96:
        return 'A'
    elif 89<= grade <=92:
        return 'A-'
    elif 85<= grade <=90:
        return 'B+'
    elif 81<= grade <=86:
        return 'B'
    elif 79<= grade <=82:
        return 'B-'
    elif 75<= grade <=80:
        return 'C+'
    elif 72<= grade <=76:
        return 'C'
    elif 64<= grade <=73:
        return 'D'
    elif 0<= grade <=65:
        return 'F'
    else:
        return 'invalide score'

def firstTerm():
    fst_sub1=int(input("Enter first term marks of the first subject: "))
    fst_sub2=int(input("Enter first term marks of the second subject: "))
    fst_sub3=int(input("Enter first term marks of the third subject: "))
    fst_sub4=int(input("Enter first term marks of the fourth subject: "))
    fst_sub5=int(input("Enter first term marks of the fifth subject: "))
    firsttermScore = (fst_sub1+fst_sub2+fst_sub3+fst_sub4+fst_sub5)/5
    return 'firsttermScore'

def midTerm():
    mid_sub1=int(input("Enter mid term marks of the first subject: "))
    mid_sub2=int(input("Enter mid term marks of the second subject: "))
    mid_sub3=int(input("Enter mid term marks of the third subject: "))
    mid_sub4=int(input("Enter mid term marks of the fourth subject: "))
    mid_sub5=int(input("Enter mid term marks of the fifth subject: "))
    midtermScore = (mid_sub1+mid_sub2+mid_sub3+mid_sub4+mid_sub5)/5
    return 'midtermScore'

def final():
    fnl_sub1=int(input("Enter final marks of the first subject: "))
    fnl_sub2=int(input("Enter final marks of the second subject: "))
    fnl_sub3=int(input("Enter final marks of the third subject: "))
    fnl_sub4=int(input("Enter final marks of the fourth subject: "))
    fnl_sub5=int(input("Enter final marks of the fifth subject: "))
    finalScore = (fnl_sub1+fnl_sub2+fnl_sub3+fnl_sub4+fnl_sub5)/5
    return 'finalScore'

total = 0
highest = 0
numStudents = int (input("How Many Students are there? "))
while numStudents < 0 or numStudents > 100:
    numStudents = int (input("Please enter a number between 0 and 100? "))

for i in range (numStudents):
    student_name = (input("Enter Student's Name Please: "))
    firstterm = firstTerm()
    midterm = midTerm()
    final = final()
    student_avg = ((firstterm) +str (midterm) +str (final)) / 3 
    if (highest < student_avg):
        highest = student_avg
        grade = student_avg  
        winner = student_name
        list_marks = []
        list_marks.append([student_name, student_avg,])
        print ("exam result: ", list_marks, "grade is: ", determine_score(grade))


print ("The Student with the higgest average is: ", winner, "With the highest average of: ", highest, "gpa is: " + determine_score(grade) )
```

Comment: Your functions do some stuff (including some calculations) then return strings. Then you call them and divide the string to 3. That an't right.

Comment: would please explain more by code ? i have problem only student_avg  almost trying for 3hour to solv it but i cant

Comment: For example, in final(), you return the string 'finalScore' rather than the variable finalScore. Same for firstTerm and midTerm. Change those functions to return the variables and check again.

Comment: In `firstTerm`, replace `return 'firsttermScore'` to `return firsttermScore` (lose the quotes), same thing for `midTerm` and `final`. then in `student_avg = ((firstterm) +str (midterm) +str (final)) / 3 ` lose the `str`s.

Comment: any1 please tell me how to list all student result thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your final print statement, you need to make sure that everything is a string:

```
print ("The Student with the higgest average is: ", winner, "With the highest average of: ", str(highest), "gpa is: " + determine_score(grade) )
```

Also your functions should return the value and not a hardcoded string:

```
return firsttermScore
...
return midtermScore
...
return finalScore
```

You also need to operate on double (or float) if you want a precise score:

```
firsttermScore = (fst_sub1+fst_sub2+fst_sub3+fst_sub4+fst_sub5)/5.0

finalScore = (fnl_sub1+fnl_sub2+fnl_sub3+fnl_sub4+fnl_sub5)/5.0

midtermScore = (mid_sub1+mid_sub2+mid_sub3+mid_sub4+mid_sub5)/5.0

student_avg = (firstterm + midterm + final) / 3.0
```

If you divide by an int, and your input data are int. The result will be an int, and you will lose your precision.

And a last print statement that would fail because list_marks is a list and not a string:

```
print ("exam result: ", str(list_marks), "grade is: ", determine_score(grade))
```

There is also a last error:

```
finalGrade = final()
```

You need to echange the name of your variable to something different from your function.

Comment: what about the student_avg?

Comment: in student_avg, you are coercing things to be a string and using the '+' sign. Strings are concatenated by the '+' sign, so you're telling the interpreter to evaluate "firsttermScoremidtermScorefinalScore"/3, which is not what you want to do.

Comment: Your 1st statement (`print`) is wrong. It should work as it is in the question.

Comment: I fixed it. In the question 'highest' is a number, and not a string. That would have crashed as well. Nonetheless did I add an unnecessary string cast.

Comment: now problem on line 62 final = final() float object is not callable

Comment: You need to change your name final_grade = final() Because there python doesn't know how to differntiate the function and the var

Comment: any1 please tell me how to list the all students result